# Pygame single push event

Tags: python, pygame

in Pygame i am trying to translate an image by 10% in each direction using each arrow key. right now the code i am using moves the image as long as the key is pushed down, what I want is for it to move only once regardless if the key is still pushed down or not.

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if (event.key == K_RIGHT):
        DISPLAYSURF.fill((255,255,255)) #Clears the screen
        translation_x(100)
        draw(1)
    if (event.key == K_LEFT):
        DISPLAYSURF.fill((255,255,255)) #Clears the screen
        translation_x(-100)
        draw(2)
    if (event.key == K_UP):
        DISPLAYSURF.fill((255,255,255)) #Clears the screen
        translation_y(100)
        draw(3)
    if (event.key == K_DOWN):
        DISPLAYSURF.fill((255,255,255)) #Clears the screen
        translation_y(-100)
        draw(4)
```

is there a simpler way of implementing this besides using time.sleep

Comment: You could stop reacting after a key's key down until you receive the corresponding key up event.

Comment: According to [pygame's documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html), there should only be one keydown event received until the key is released and subsequently pressed again.  Are you sure receiving continuous keydown events is the source of your problem?

Comment: ktodisco is right. What is 'draw(int)' doing? --- The other method is get key state which polls if the key is held down.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pygame.key.set_repeat()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat) to disable repeated events from keys that are still down.

However, it should be disabled by default:

> When the keyboard repeat is enabled, keys that are held down will generate multiple pygame.KEYDOWN events. The delay is the number of milliseconds before the first repeated pygame.KEYDOWN will be sent. After that another pygame.KEYDOWN will be sent every interval milliseconds. If no arguments are passed the key repeat is disabled.
>
> When pygame is initialized the key repeat is disabled